# Running Laravel Horizon on shared hosting via CRON

Tags: laravel, cron, shared-hosting, laravel-horizon

I am running an application build on Laravel 8. This application handles heavy loads of jobs. That is why my queues are stored in Redis and handled by Laravel Horizon.

Since I am on shared hosting, I have no access to Supervisord (or to any process manager).

I am asking the community because I was unable to find any advice or recommendation on the preferred configuration for my case.

CRON

`*   *   *   *   *   php artisan schedule:run >/dev/null 2>&1`

Console / Kernel.php

`$schedule->command('horizon')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();`

What is the preferred method of keeping Horizon alive via CRON?

What is the preferred method to prevent Horizon duplicate processes (and to prevent memory leaks)?

Comment: maybe you can try from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53662547/6170975

Answer (score 2):

Since you can run cron jobs, you could create a file 'start_horizon.php':

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

$res = shell_exec("php artisan horizon:status");

if($res !== "Horizon is running.\n") {
    echo "horizon is not running, starting it\n";
    $fp = popen("php artisan horizon", "r");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $buffer = fgets($fp, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
    }
    echo "horizon was terminated\n";
    pclose($fp);
} else {
    echo "horizon is running\n";
}
```

and call it from cron every minute or so. This script will check if horizon is running. If horizon running, it will exit. If horizon is not running, it will start horizon.

The cron line should look like this:

```
* * * * * cd /your/laravel/dir/ && php start_horizon.php >> /dev/null
```

It is needed to run this script in a directory where `artisan` is available.

Comment: Nice approach. It prevents overlapping while continuously restarts horizon. One suggestion or improvement from my side is that I think it would be better to have this helper as a custom artisan command. This way there is no need for a second cron call and laravel scheduler can call the custom artisan command which handles horizon checking and restart.

Comment: I played around with this idea, before I posted my solution, and found that the laravel scheduler is not the best place to do this kind of check-and-restart function. I had to check for much more cases than the cron job above.

Comment: @ahofmann I'm facing the same problem now and I really like your solution. I indeed have the question as Márk Cserepes, so could you elaborate a bit more on why that isn't a good idea? 

For me it would sound more logical to keep everything into one Laravel project instead of having a project and littering the server with additional separate cron job files?

Comment: @ralphjsmit I fear that I can't give a satisfactory answer to this. I tried to use the scheduler of Laravel instead of a cron job. It didn't work right away, and that's why I solved it with cron jobs. Cron jobs are good, they do their job (pun intended) and they are the best solution for me.

Comment: @ahofmann Thanks for coming back to me! Sorry for the somewhat late response, SO’s notifications aren’t perfect.. ;-) I’ll try this out next week as an artisan command and let you know how it works for me!